# Как вернуть курсор в конец слова EditText?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вернуть курсор в конец слова (нужно при первичном открытии )

так не получается

```
  EditText el1 = (EditText) findViewById(editText);
        el1.setSelection(el1.getText().length());
```

использую

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/writing"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        tools:targetApi="o" />
```

Comment: Если *при первичном открытии* - откуда тогда взялось "hello"? Ваша проблема в том, что в конце текста стоит символ новой строки - если он не нужен, просто уберите. Если нужен, тогда надо искать последний печатный символ и ставить курсор после него.

Comment: как найти последний печатный символ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так сработало для меня 
если не писать -1
(то текст получается с новой  строки что не удобно )

```
  EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()-1);
```